# i have two sites, site.com1 and site2.com I want to check is user logged in on site2 from site1 using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cross-domain, session-cookies

I have two sites, site1.com and site2.com
I want to check is a user logged in on site2 from site1 using PHP.

I tried using AJAX but not worked, and cookies cannot be created on other domain.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Arun,

The code where you've written the login validation, you can get the domain you're currently on.

In PHP use **$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']** directly OR parse **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**
Save this to a DB field

Using JS you can use **window.location.hostname** to get the domain name from where you are logging in. Post that to an ajax call along with login details for validation. If success, save it to a DB field.

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: thanks for the reply.
I want to check isUserLoggedIn to site2.com from site1.com, just like login with Facebook, log in with google... I want to login site1.com if a user logged in to site2.com.
any reference code is much appreciatable.